# Mule json schema validation

Tags: json, mule, mule-component

I am trying to use Validate JSON schema component in Mule flow and I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException for the json that is passed. Below is the json schema, json sample and code of Mule flow. Can you please point me where am I doing mistake?

Json schema:

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "object",

   "properties": {

      "id": {
         "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
         "type": "integer"
      },

      "name": {
         "description": "Name of the product",
         "type": "string"
      },

      "price": {
         "type": "number",
         "minimum": 0,
         "exclusiveMinimum": true
      }
   },

   "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
```

Json passed to POST method:

```
[
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "An ice sculpture",
      "price": 12.50,
   },

   {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "A blue mouse",
      "price": 25.50,
   }
]
```

Error :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@6e7f030; line: 6, column: 5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
```

Mule Flow:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="jsonschemavalidationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:validate-schema schemaLocation="jsonschema.json" doc:name="Validate JSON Schema"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Muleflow:<flow name="jsonschemavalidationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:validate-schema schemaLocation="jsonschema.json" doc:name="Validate JSON Schema"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few errors in both the JSON and the Schema as follows:-
There is an extra comma`,` after  `"price": 12.50`
So the Valid JSON will be :-

```
[
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "An ice sculpture",
      "price": 12.50
   },

   {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "A blue mouse",
      "price": 25.50
   }
]
```

In JSON Schema file ***jsonschema.json*** There are two errors:-
You need to put "`type": "array"` instead of `"type": "object"`
and next is `"exclusiveMinimum": true` seems to be invalid with this JSON input...
So, the correct working JSON schema will be :-

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "array",

   "properties": {

      "id": {
         "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
         "type": "integer"
      },

      "name": {
         "description": "Name of the product",
         "type": "string"
      },

      "price": {
         "type": "number",
         "minimum": 0
      }
   },

   "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
```

Try it.. it will work fine :)

Comment: Thanks @Anirban-sen-chowdhary......it worked with keeping "exclusiveMinimum": true as well.

Answer (score 0):

The json u r passing is not proper. It has an extra comma ',' after price: 12.50. Even after second price element also an extra comma is added.
Just remove it and it works fine.